# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in CREATE DATABASE

Tags: database, oracle

I keep getting the same error while creating a database. It seems like something is wrong with the syntax. Here is how I create it:

```
CREATE DATABASE darkarmy
USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY admin
USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY admin
LOGFILE GROUP 1 ('/u01/zdw07/logs/redo01a.log') SIZE 10M,
GROUP 2 ('/u01/zdw07/logs/redo02a.log') SIZE 10M,
GROUP 3 ('/u01/zdw07/logs/redo03a.log') SIZE 10M,
GROUP 4 ('/u01/zdw07/logs/redo04a.log’) SIZE 10M
MAXLOGFILES 5
MAXLOGMEMBERS 5
MAXLOGHISTORY 10
MAXDATAFILES 50
CHARACTER SET UTF8
NATIONAL CHARACTER SET UTF8
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
DATAFILE '/u01/zdw07/darkarmy/node03/upike69.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
SYSAUX DATAFILE '/u01/zdw07/darkarmy/node02/jap41.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED,
'/u01/zdw07/darkarmy/node02/nud37.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
DATAFILE '/u01/zdw07/darkarmy/node03/arulice693.dbf'
SIZE 50M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
TEMPFILE '/u01/zdw07/darkarmy/temp01.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE
UNDO TABLESPACE undotbs1
DATAFILE '/u01/zdw07/darkarmy/undotbs1.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

The error message:

'/u01/zdw07/darkarmy/node03/upike69.dbf' SIZE 100M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
*

ERROR at line 16:

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I am new to Oracle, would be grateful for any help!

Comment: You have a special quote on the end of `redo04a` so it thinks that you are still specifying this file name.

Comment: Just check syntax highlighting in the question code

Comment: Any reason why your not using Oracle tool dbca?

Comment: Thanks, everyone!

Comment: @Beefstu basically, this is my studying task, so one of the conditions is to do it via sqlplus

Comment: _"so one of the conditions is to do it via sqlplus"_  Ah, but as a learning exercise, you could have used dbca to generate a script, then compared that with your own effort.

Comment: @EdStevens Oh, great, I’ll try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem here:

GROUP 4 ('/u01/zdw07/logs/redo04a.log’) SIZE 10M

The closing quote is ’ when it should be '

Comment: woow, this is right. Thank you so much!!